# Compute and Display spectrum using Qwt/FFTW3?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, fftw, qwt

I would like to make real time audio processing with Qt and display the spectrum using FFTW3.

- What I've done in steps:

  1. I capture any sound from computer device and fill it into the buffer.
  2. I assign sound samples to double array
  3. I compute the fundamental frequency.

**Problem:**

- oblique /straight lines appears on spectrum
- I found out that these straight lines correspond to the maximum sample in buffer
- and to the max frequency

here are my code and images of spectrum

[image: signal1]
[image: signal2]

```
QByteArray *buffer;
QAudioInput *audioInput;
audioInput = new QAudioInput(format, this);

//Check the number of samples in input buffer
 qint64 len = audioInput->bytesReady();

//Limit sample size
if(len > 4096)
len = 4096;

//Read sound samples from input device to buffer
qint64 l = input->read(buffer.data(), len);
int input_size= BufferSize;
int output_size = input_size; //input_size/2+1;
fftw_plan p3;
double in[output_size];
fftw_complex out[output_size];

short *outdata = (short*)m_buffer.data();// assign sample into short array
int data_size = size_t(outdata);
int data_size1 = sizeof(outdata);

int count = 0;
double w = 0;

for(int i(chanelNumber); i < output_size/2; i= i + 2) //fill array in
{

    w= 0.5 * (1 - cos(2*M_PI*i/output_size)); // Hann Windows 
    double x = 0;
    if(i < data_size){
        x = outdata[i];
    }
    if(count < output_size){
      in[count] = x;// fill Array In with sample from buffer 
      count++;
    }
}

for(int i=count; i<output_size; i++){
    in[i] = 0;
}
p3 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(output_size, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);// create Plan 
fftw_execute(p3);// FFT
for (int i = 0; i < (output_size/2); i++) {
    double r1 = out[i][0] * out[i][0];
    double im1 = out[i][3] * out[i][4];
    double t1 = r1 + im1;
    //double t = 20*log(sqrt(t1));
    double t = sqrt(t1)/(double)(output_size/2);
    double f = (double)i*8000  / ((double)output_size/2);
    const QPointF s2(f, t);
    SignalData::instance(2).append( s2 );
}

fftw_destroy_plan(p3);

return 0;
```

Comment: hi I see you have made some progress since last time, your issue looks like wrong draw of the FFT output (frequency domain plot). check if you draw lines only for relevant data (FFT output is on complex domain so do not forget to ignore the imaginary number part) and also use only first half of the output because FFT is symetric for real domain input data which gets you frequencies up to half of input sample rate (as expected from Nyquist–Shannon-Kotelnikov-Whittaker sampling theorem)

Comment: just in case 1st signal images looks OK (single impulse is set of many sin-wave frequencies together to eliminate the periodicity) the 2nd is bugged with the lines.

Comment: @Spektre, Thanks for your response , the spectrum graph  is magnitude=f(frequency), magnitude =sqrt(out[i][0] * out[i][0] + out[i][1] * out[i][1]); why should I ignore the imaginary number part?

Comment: if I remember correctly then the imaginary part represents phase of then sin wave frequency and real part the amplitude but try to google it a bit if it is really true (I prefer DCT for frequency analysis so I am not 100% sure of all FFT properties)

Comment: I believe the magnitude is the amplitude and the arctangent is the phase.